# Java Command-Line Input

Tags: java, input

New to the world of Java and I was wondering how to make a program that when run takes input in this form:

```
java ProgramName 1 2 3 4 5
```

That is, it takes 1,2,3,4 and 5 as inputs for the program. I'm guessing that it will take this as a string and that somehow I will need to convert this string to individual numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `args` in `main` is an array that contains the command-line arguments as strings. The following code will loop through the arguments and print them.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```

For more information, have look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, the entry point of a standalone java application is the method:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

In your case, the `args[]` array will be `{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}`

To convert any of those strings to int you can use the following code:

```
int firstParameter = Interger.parseInt(args[0]);
int secondParameter = Interger.parseInt(args[1]);
// etc
```

For further info refer to the Official Java Trails:

- [Command-Line Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)
- [Numbers and Strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `main()` method. It can accept an array of `String` objects called `args` which are your command-line arguments:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   // Code goes here.
}
```

Comment: the method `main` needs to be `public static`. just a thought.